# Acessing Objects and Assigning Variables

Tags: javascript

I'm working through the course "Javascript: From Fundamentals to Functional JS", and I have a question about objects. I wrote this code as an answer to

`'make the line box[innerBox2].full = false'` not throw an error.

**edit - changed the names of some variables to (hopefully) make it clearer where I'm confused**

My answer is as follows:

```
var box = {};

//Initialize the property box.myInnerBox to empty object
box.myInnerBox = {};

//Create a new variable to point to the value of box.MyInnerBox, which should be an empty object
var insideBox = box.myInnerBox;

box[insideBox].full = false; // Throws Error
```

But this doesn't work. It seems to be that it doesn't like it when I assign var innerBox2 to box.innerBox2. Why does the above not work, while the code below does? Specifically, how does it know that 'otherBox' is a property of box without first referencing box? Why can't I assign a variable to a property of box? **My question is not about how to use bracket vs dot notation. My question is why assigning `var innerBox2` to the value of `box.innerBox2` does not work**

```
var box ={};
box.otherBox = {};

var innerBox2 = 'otherBox';

box[innerBox2].full = false; // No Error
```

Thanks very much.

Comment: `box[innerBox2]` is not the same as `box.innerBox2`.

Comment: That's why I'm trying to set it as such with the line `var innerBox2 = box.innerBox2`. Why doesn't this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, let's start with why the second one works.

Basically you have two ways of accessing object properties: `someObject.someProperty` and `someObject['someProperty']`

What you are doing in the second case is assigning `string` 'otherBox' to variable named innerBox2 and then trying to access an object's property by asking the object for a property with the name given in the variable like so `box[innerBox2]` which translates to `box['otherBox']`.

Now to the first case. You had created an object and a property on it which had the value of an empty object `{}`. Then you assigned the value returned from `box.innerBox2` to a variable named `innerBox2`. The variable holds now a value which is just an empty object, it literally is this `var innerBox2 = {}`. Now you were trying to access a property on the `box` object which only had `innerBox2` property with a value of empty object. But by doing `box[innerBox2]` now literally means `box[{}]` which does not make sense and thus the error.

I hope it made sense to you. Feel free to ask anything more it it was unclear.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are having is an understanding of how objects work in javascript - please refer to the following: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects

To answer your question, the first example doesn't work because you are using bracket notation on an object. Bracket notation must take a string (otherwise it will convert whatever you input into a string which may not be what you expect) - this is why the second example DOES work.

Try these two code snippets, they are equivalent:

```
var box = {};
box.innerBox = {};
box.innerBox.filled = false;
```

and

```
var box = {};
box['innerBox'] = {};
box['innerBox']['filled'] = false;
```

bracket notation and dot notation can be used interchangeably. Dot notation is better for readability, is generally more convenient. Bracket notation is useful if you want to set/get based on a variable which you can pass into the bracket.

Comment: Right, I understand that in `box[innerBox2].fill = false;` innerBox2 must be a variable. That is why I tried to assign `var innerBox2` to `box.innerBox2` which I already initialized as an empty object, thinking that this would assign the variable innerBox2 to the value of box.innerBox2, which is an empty object. My question is why assigning `box.innerBox2` to a variable throws an error.

Comment: @EFH In the case you are describing, `box[innerBox2]`, `innerBox2` does not have to be a variable. It can be. It DOES have to be a string.

Comment: @EFH The expression used in bracket notation must be a string, so it will be converting to a string. The toString() of an object is `[object Object]` so in fact `box[innerBox2].full = false` is like saying `box['[object Object]'.full = false;` which gives an error because `box['[object Object]'` is `undefined`. If you had a line before that like `box['[object Object]' = {};` it wouldn't throw an error.

Comment: To put it more clearly, if you want to make the line `box[innerBox2].full = false` not throw an error (after you have defined box and innerBox2 as objects), all you have to do is change the line to `box['innerBox2'].full = false;`

Comment: Well, the goal was to get the original statement `box[innerBox2].full = false` to not throw an error. That means that because `innerBox2` is not in quotes, it must be a variable. That's why I assigned `var innerBox2 = box.innerBox2`,  a property that was already initialized with `box.innerBox2 = {}`. So my question is, when I set `var innerBox2 = box.innerBox2` (innerBox2 being already initialized as an empty object), why can't the var innerBox2 point to the value of box.innerBox2?

Comment: @EFH I just explained why, `innerBox2.toString()` is `'[object Object]'`, so that is the property you access whenever you write `box[innerBox2]` after that point. You could see that by assigning something `box[innerBox2] = {};` and then checking `console.log( box );`. If you wanted it to refer to the property `innerBox2` then you would use `var innerBox2 = 'innerBox2';` instead of `var innerBox2 = box.innerBox2;`.

Comment: @EFH Because setting a variable `innerBox2 = box.innerBox2` is setting the variable to the object itself. Try `var innerBox2 = "innerBox2";` and it should work. The salient point is that if you want to use a variable, the variable must equal a string, not an object.

Answer (score 1):

The bracket notation expects a string whose value is the name of the property. If you use an object, then it is converted into a String.

`innerBox2` ends up being converted to the String "[object Object]" so that's the property it's trying to access, not "innerBox2".

Comment: Is it not true that without quotes around it, it will expect `innerBox2` in `box[innerBox2]` to be a variable (in other words, to act as an index)? The second example works fine, it's just that rather than setting `var innerBox2` equal to `'otherBox'`, I set `var innerBox2` equal to `box.innerBox2` (this is probably where the confusion is coming from, I may need to change the names to make it clearer) in order to set it to the **value** of box.innerBox2, which is an empty object.